# Custom domain name in AWS Gateway API configured with TLS v.1.0 but seems in practice to be using TLS v.1.2. How can this be?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, tls1.2

I have an API hosted on Amazon API Gateway with a custom domain name. It is set to use TLS v.1.0 but when I monitor the traffic between the client and server it appears to be using TLS v.1.2.

How can it be that TLS v.1.2 is used when it is configured to be using TLS v.1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't lock down API Gateway to TLS v1.0. You can only [set the minimum allowed TLS version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-custom-domain-tls-version.html). You currently have it set to allow TLS version 1.0 or higher, and whatever you are using to connect is using TLS version 1.2.

[TLS version 1.0 and 1.1 are considered insecure these days](https://www.packetlabs.net/tls-1-1-no-longer-secure/), and it is recommended that you require 1.2 as the minimum TLS version now. The client you are using to connect to API Gateway is just trying to be more secure by attempting to use TLS 1.2.